# pass a function to a custom react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

Previously, I was using a graphql query like this. The data is returned from the query and I use `setShowFlatList`with the `data`returned:

```
  const [loadUsers, { data }] = useUsersLazyQuery({
    onCompleted: () => {
      setShowFlatList(data);
    },
});
```

Now I am creating a custom react hook where I use this graphql query. It looks like this:

```
export const useLoadUsers = (onCompleted: any) => {
  const [usersQuery, { data }] = useUsersLazyQuery({
    onCompleted: () => {
      if(onCompleted){
        onCompleted();
      }
    },
    onError: onLoadUserError,
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  });

const loadUsers = async (
phoneNumber: number,
) => {
  const data = await usersQuery({
    variables: {
      where: {
        OR: [
          { phoneNumber: newPhoneNumber }
        ],
      },
    },
    });
  return data;
};
return loadUsers;
};
```

But I cannot figure out how to pass the `setShowFlatList` function to the `onCompleted` of the hook, such that I can still use `data`as its parameter from within the hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: The `onCompleted` should also have an parameter data, so you can use that one.

```
export const useLoadUsers = (onCompleted: any) => {
  const [usersQuery, { data }] = useUsersLazyQuery({
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      if(onCompleted){
        onCompleted(data);
      }
    },
    onError: onLoadUserError,
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  });

const loadUsers = async (
phoneNumber: number,
) => {
  const data = await usersQuery({
    variables: {
      where: {
        OR: [
          { phoneNumber: newPhoneNumber }
        ],
      },
    },
    });
  return data;
};
return loadUsers;
};
```

Comment: The callback is optional, as it is an empty function by default.

Comment: @Jnl When you first call the hook, pass the callback function like so: `const editLocationName = useEditLocationName(callbackFunction);`. e.g.  `useEditLocationName(() => console.log('Completed'););`

Comment: Thanks. But I realised this won't exactly work for me since I also need to pass a parameter inside setShowFlatList and not just a string. That parameter will be from within the hook. Could you see the updated question please?

Comment: So you want to use `data` in `customCallback`?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please check, if this works for you.

Comment: But still, how will I use it while calling the hook on any screen? I cannot use ```setShowFlatList(data);```because data is undefined and I can also not use ```setShowFlatList```as because it requires a parameter.

Comment: The onCompleted doesn't need a parameter. The data that I want to set is from ```[usersQuery, { data }]```.

Comment: @Linschlager but how can I set ```data``` with it?

Comment: I don't understand what you need. Could you provide a live code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```
export const useEditLocationName = (callback) => {
  return (params) => async(favouritePlaceId, customisedName) => {
    const [updateFavouritePlace] = useUpdateFavouritePlaceMutation({
      onCompleted: () => {
        if(callback){
          callback(params)
        }
        Alert.alert('Name aktualisiert');
      },
      onError: () => {
        Alert.alert('Oops, etwas ist schiefgelaufen');
      },
    });
    updateFavouritePlace({
      variables: {
        favouritePlaceId: favouritePlaceId,
        input: { customisedName: customisedName },
      },
    });
    return null;
  }

const editLocationName = useEditLocationName(setShowFlatList);
...
  const handleSubmitForm = (
    values: FormValues,
  ) => {
    editLocationName(params)(route.params.favouritePlaceId, values.locationName)
  };


/*
export const useEditLocationName = (callback) => {
  const [updateFavouritePlace] = useUpdateFavouritePlaceMutation({
    onCompleted: () => {
      if(callback){
        callback()
      }
      Alert.alert('Name aktualisiert');
    },
    onError: () => {
      Alert.alert('Oops, etwas ist schiefgelaufen');
    },
  });

  const editLocationName = async (
    favouritePlaceId: number,
    customisedName: string,
  ) => {
    updateFavouritePlace({
      variables: {
        favouritePlaceId: favouritePlaceId,
        input: { customisedName: customisedName },
      },
    });
    return null;
  };

  return editLocationName;
};
*/
....
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I need to pass ```data``` into the ```setFlatList``` and ```data```is from the hook itself. ```const [usersQuery, { data }] = useUsersLazyQuery```I have already updated the code.

Comment: is `useUsersLazyQuery`  and  `useLoadUsers `  the same thing?

Comment: useLoadUsers is the custom hook that I am creating. useUsersLazyQuery is a custom graphql hook, not a part of this code.

Comment: you mean you want to use `const [loadUsers, { data }] ...`  the `{data}` in the `useUsersLazyQuery`?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the {data} returned from ```const [loadUsers, { data }]``` in ```setShowFlatList(data)```.

Comment: maybe you need change another way. because you can't get the result while using it